# Server error in asp net mvc project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config

I have a website that works with mvc. I get this error sometimes  [image]
 I do not make any changes on the server or the project.This error occurs particularly at night.I do not take backups that hour.
I am not receiving any errors from the server.in web.config targetFramework

```
< compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6" />
```

What could be the reason for this? what i need to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem with your framework version . As error message species.

To solve this firstly make sure the target net framework version must be 4.0 up .

Also , check that mentioned framework version must be installed also install latest release of net framework version like 4.6 , 4.7 etc.

After installing restart the ide , recompile the project , so it reconfigure itself.

Hope, it solve the error.